# How can I succinctly combine many `Result`s of different types?

Tags: rust

Currently I use this pattern:

```
let a: Result<A, ParseError> = parseA();
let b: Result<B, ParseError> = parseB();
let c: Result<C, ParseError> = parseC();
a.and_then(|a| b.map(|b| (a, b))).and_then(|(a,b)| c.map(|c| {
  // finally the crux of what I want to do
  a.foo(b).bar(c)
}))
```

Is there a more succinct way to define `a`, `b` & `c`, such as Scala's for-expression?

Comment: This isn't exactly "combining results" as you're attempting to here.. however lately I've [been doing this - combining the parsing in the iteration when summing everything together](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=9470f7e9f293852f7444c1017ae91fa9&version=stable). I'm not sure if this is suitable for you though, given its much harder to know which one failed in this scenario (if any do).

Comment: I like it. Although it's not what I need and makes me realise my question is a bit misleading. I'll have another go at writing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually wrap everything in layers instead of chaining through tuples:

```
let result = a.and_then(|a| {
    b.and_then(|b| {
        c.map(|c| {
            a.foo(b).bar(c)
        })
    })
});
```

Or, in recent Rust versions, you can make elaborate use of the `?` operator:

```
let result = a.and_then(|a| {
    a.foo(b?).bar(c?)
});
```

Closures allow you to do this nicely and safely.

Of course this does not work if you want to store an intermediate `Result` in a variable.

Comment: Wouldn't `a?.foo(b?).bar(c?)` also work? Or even: `parseA()?.foo(parseB()?).bar(parseC()?)`, with the latter not performing the `parseB` if `parseA` fails, and so on.

Comment: Only if your function returns a `Result`. If you want to manually process it, then not. Even if you return a `Result` you need to decide between `Ok(a?.foo(b?))` and `a.and_then(|a| a.foo(b?))`, which, depending on your real code might cause the latter to be more readable (in serde we have this situation frequently).